# Perl escape wild card character when matching hash keys

Tags: regex, perl

Please suggest how to escape wild card character found in hash keys.

```
print "pattern exists\n" if /.ISPV3-21*02/ ~~ %reads;
```

Thanks

Comment: (1) Unfortunately, I must say: don't use `~~`. It's broken and subject to massive changes. (2) Did you try, um, escaping it?  Like `\*`? I presume you want a literal `.` so you escape that, too, and the `-` should be escaped as well.  A systemic way: `\Q`, like `/\Q$pattern/`. See docs

Comment: (by "broken" I meant to say that it is, for all I know, widely considered to be broken in its current form)

Comment: @zdim Sorry to be pedantic, but `-` only needs to be escaped when it's in a bracketed character class, and even then only when it's not at the beginning or end of the class.

Comment: @mwp  Thanks for stating/correcting it, my comment was too coarse with `-`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that smartmatch (`~~`) is experimental, so it's discouraged to use it.* For this task you can use [any from List::Util](https://perldoc.pl/List::Util#any) or on older perls [grep](https://perldoc.pl/functions/grep) can serve the same purpose.

If you are trying to match an exact string, use [quotemeta](https://perldoc.pl/functions/quotemeta) which can also be written as `\Q` in an interpolated string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 1.33 'any';
print "pattern exists\n" if any { m/\Q.ISPV3-21*02/ } keys %reads;
```

You can also use the [index](https://perldoc.pl/functions/index) function to find an exact substring.

```
print "pattern exists\n" if any { index($_, '.ISPV3-21*02') >= 0 } keys %reads;
```

If you are trying to match the whole key, and not just a substring within the key, you need to anchor the regex match with `\A` (beginning of string, same as `^`) and `\z` (end of string).

```
print "pattern exists\n" if any { m/\A\Q.ISPV3-21*02\E\z/ } keys %reads;
```

But this is the same as just testing for [string equality](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Equality-Operators).

```
print "pattern exists\n" if any { $_ eq '.ISPV3-21*02' } keys %reads;
```

And that's also the same as just checking if the key [exists](https://perldoc.pl/functions/exists), since you are looking through the keys of a hash.

```
print "pattern exists\n" if exists $reads{'.ISPV3-21*02'};
```

*Smartmatch was [retroactively made experimental](https://perldoc.pl/perl5180delta#The-smartmatch-family-of-features-are-now-experimental) as part of the introduction of experimental features, due to its overcomplicated ruleset (you have to go through the [whole table](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Smartmatch-Operator) in the docs to figure out what any two operands, as well as each of their contents, will resolve to) and the same string/number ambiguity as [bitwise operators](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Bitwise-String-Operators). It has had several iterations of proposed changes and is likely at some point to be deprecated or incompatibly changed, so it should not be relied upon.

Comment: Curious about the reason to do it with `index` as well -- efficiency? I'd expect it to be faster than starting up regex?

Comment: @zdim No particular reason, just an alternative that some might find cleaner. I find the efficiency in comparison to regex varies and is almost never significant.

Comment: @zdim, The regex engine does take up a relatively long time to start up, yes. However, the simplicity of using it is virtually always worth the cost.

Comment: i have a side question. What if i wanted to compare hash keys to elements in an array, instead of a single string. What is the correct way to do this? thanks

Comment: @user3781528 You'd have to be more specific. Hash keys and array elements are both lists, so you are not just searching for an item in a list. Do you want to find if the lists contain the same elements? If one list is contained within another? If they simply share at least one element?